# C# WPF DataGrid Path layers

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to have a dataGrid that have a list of paths.
But not all paths are the same.
I want it that the user can distinguish which path is lower or higher.

I tried it with counting the backslash char '\' and add "--" for each infront of the name. This wasnt really the solution but could be seen.

Is there a way to build like a tree in a dataGrid?

Comment: The TreeView control wouldn't work better to achieve this?

Comment: @IsmaC. not really, because the dataGrid holds much more inofmration besides the path. It holds like the name, the version and the date. I just want it so the user can easily see, "oh thats not the same directory"